# Clang typecasting using C++11 has ambiguous compiler behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

Consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
  template< typename T> 
  operator vector< T >() const {
    return vector< T >();
  }

  template< typename T> 
  operator T() const {
    return T();
  }
};

int main () {
  Foo b;
  vector< int >  q = b;
  q = b;
}
```

Compiling this with Clang or g++ using either of the two commands:

```
g++ test.cpp
clang++ test.cpp
```

Enabling C++11 features, however, it fails:

```
g++ --std=c++0x test.cpp
clang++ --std=c++11 test.cpp
```

The error message reads as follows:

```
test.cpp:20:5: error: use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'vector<int>' and 'Foo')
  q = b;
  ~ ^ ~
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:373:7: note: candidate function
      operator=(vector&& __x)
      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:362:7: note: candidate function
      operator=(const vector& __x);
      ^
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:394:7: note: candidate function
      operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
      ^
1 error generated.
```

It is unclear to me why it works without C++11, while it fails with. Moveover, note that the line

```
vector< int >  q = b; // In the main function, line 19
```

in the main function does not cause an error. Can anyone explain why it does not work, and what one can do to make it work with C++11?

Comment: It seems that it might be a bug in LLVM 3.0. Compiling with LLVM 3.1 it works.

Comment: @Xeo, Just do that. I also feel sure that it is bug. However, it still seems to be parts of it in Clang 3.1 since q = vector< int >(b); fails while q = b works.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I mixed something up. Rethinking stuff now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no compiler bug here.  Your code is broken in C++11, because C++11 added more converting constructors and more overloads for the assignment operator.

This is the risk you run when you make a type that converts to absolutely anything (using templated conversion).  `Foo` is just as happy to convert itself to an `initializer_list<int>` as a `vector<int>`.

The reason that

```
vector<int> q = b;
```

works in Clang 3.1, while

```
vector<int> q(b);
```

fails, is that the first is *copy-initialization*, which requires an *implicit* conversion to `vector<int>` followed by a copy-constructor call, while the second is *direct-initialization* which performs an *explicit* conversion.  The set of candidates for implicit conversion is smaller, because constructors marked `explicit` are removed, resolving the ambiguity.

The difference between Clang 3.0 and 3.1 is likely a library compliance fix, which marked additional constructors as `explicit`, not a change to compiler behavior.

Comment: You are completely right. The behaviour is caused by the initializer list introduced in C++11. To overcome this problem one adds:   template< typename T > operator std::initializer_list< T >() = delete; which disables conversion to initializer_list. Thanks.